# Как включить режим добавления вершин без режима редактирования?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Когда я вызываю `startDrawing` для объекта `geometryEditor.LineString`, у меня помимо режима добавления новых вершин включается режим редактирования, т.е. я вижу точки на вершинах и в серединах рёбер. Вызов `stopEditing` прекращает не только режим редактирования, но и режим добавления вершин. Можно ли управлять этими двумя режимами по отдельности?

Мне нужно, чтобы в режиме добавления вершин не было видно точек на рёбрах и вершинах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день. Режима рисовать без редактирования в API Яндекс.карт нет.
Единственно решение задачи - это самостоятельно реализовать похожее поведение.

Comment: Добавте в вопрос пример реализации похожего поведения.

Comment: В данном случае все очень сильно от задачи зависит.

Comment: Если задача не ясна, зачем вы даёте ответ?

Comment: Ответ в том, что необходимого поведения в API карт нет.

Answer (score 0):

примерно nfr

```
//Ловим событие перед перетаскиванием вершины.
polygon.editor.events.add("beforevertexdragstart", function (event) {

//Отменяем событие перетаскивания   
    Event.preventDefault();
    });
```

При этом новые вершины будут двигаться - у них свои события (edgedrag)